How does Jump work?
Under the 2024 rules, the Jump spell was substantially changed to say:

You touch a willing creature. Once on each of its turns until the spell ends, that creature can jump up to 30 feet by spending 10 feet of movement.

Of additional relevance are the Long Jump rules:

When you make a Long Jump, you leap horizontally a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet immediately before the jump. When you make a standing Long Jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, each foot you jump costs a foot of movement.

and the High Jump rules:

When you make a High Jump, you leap into the air a number of feet equal to 3 plus your Strength modifier (minimum of 0 feet) if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing High Jump, you can jump only half that distance. Either way, each foot of the jump costs a foot of movement.

What is the correct way to interpret the effect of the Jump spell? For the purpose of this question, assume the target has a movement speed of 30 feet.

Hella Buffed Interpretation: The creature is able to move 20 feet and then spend their remaining movement to jump (either as a Long Jump or High Jump) 30 additional feet, a net of 50 feet of movement.

A lot of content creators seem to take this interpretation, which seems to support the notion of the spell being substantially buffed and may also be Rules as Intended.

It's a Poor Man's Fly: The creature is able to spend 10 feet of their movement to jump 30 feet (either as a Long Jump or a High Jump) but afterwards they cannot move any further unless they take the Dash action, a net of 30 feet of movement.

This interpretation is less generous than the first, but sort of strives to strike a balance whereby so long as you have movement (i.e. movement speed is reduced to 0) you can always achieve 30' of movement in a manner that doesn't involve touching the ground.

You can Ignore the Normal Jumping Strength Requirements Only: The creature is able to spend 10 feet of their movement to jump 30 feet (either as a Long Jump or a High Jump) but will only be able to utilize 20 feet of that distance due to them only having 20 feet of movement left, a net of 20 feet of movement.

This is the least generous interpretation, but sort of makes Jump a spell that might be used situationally, perhaps as a counter to aerial attacks. Alternately, it might be more useful for allies that have inherently higher movement speeds like Monks and Barbarians, which would be very similar to how the 2014 version of the spell worked.

Some other interpretation.

Other thoughts I'd had on this is that maybe it can only be used for Long Jumps, but as I was researching I couldn't really find anything that would impose that restriction. Or that the 30 feet of jump distance would be halved if the target didn't move 10' first. Regardless, I'm sure there might be other interpretations.

Number 1, "Hella Buffed"
The way the rules are written, jump is not a natural language term, it is a defined game term in the glossary (on p. 370) "Jumping", which tells you

When you jump, you make either a Long Jump (horizontal) or a High Jump (vertical). See also “Long Jump” and “High Jump.”

The PHB also explains on p. 8:

The game also includes elements—class features, feats, weapon properties, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and the like—that sometimes contradict a general rule. When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception
wins.

So the question is in how far the spell text "contradicts" the general rules for jumping. It does so by stating you jump up to 30 feet by spending 10 feet.
The spell tells you that you can "jump" 30 feet. That means you make a Long or High Jump of 30 feet. That part I think is clear -- it will always be 30 feet, as the exception overrules the normal distances of the Long or High jump. If you were limited by the Long or High jump strength or movement rules, you would end up not actually jumping 30 feet, but the spell says that you do. This also means that the limitation the normal jumping rules impose for not first moving 10 feet before jumping are irrelevant.
The more difficult part is if you consume additional movement by those jumps. I don't think you do, because the spell says you jump those 30 feet by spending 10 feet of movement, not after spending 10 feet of movement, so the 10 feet of movement are what replaces the normal cost to jump these 30 feet (which would be 30 feet of normal movement).
If this was worded as "you spend 10 feet of movement, then jump 30 feet", it would be your number 2, "Poor Man's Fly", the jump would still be for 30 feet, but would be a normal jump otherwise and consume all your movement.
I think this "Hella Buffed" interpretation is also not too strong. The extra movement you are getting out of it is +20 feet for one minute if your base speed is 30 feet. Compare this to the Expeditious Retreat spell, which also is a level 1 spell and allows you to an extra dash every turn, worth a full +30 feet for up to 10 minutes (with concentration on self), or the Longstrider spell which allows you to get a +10 speed for a full hour.

That’ this sounds right. It’s only “Hella” buffed at 10/30 ft. It’s actually less powerful than the 2014 Jump.

@nonymous I wouldn't call it less powerful in general. In 2014 you had to spend movement for your jump, so in practice you only got to jump 20 ft. most of the time. 30 ft. movement speed - 10 ft. running start. If you have enough strength but to need a running start, you're still limited by movement speed. The 2014 version is stronger only for a character with high strength and high movement speed (or using dash).

+1 Good point. This difference makes jumping more accessible and fun for all PCs. :)

The spell says you jump up to 30 feet. Not exactly 30 feet.

@InternetHobo You are right, I updated the text. It still also allows you to jump 30 feet, if you want to.

@JoakimM.H. you’re only considering characters that neither dash nor have a speed faster than 30. The 2014 jump was outright more powerful.

@nonymous was the 2014 version really more powerful? I mean, I guess it was if you cast it on characters who can use a Bonus Action to Dash and thereby take advantage of the full distance it grants, but I think most characters would like to have their Action when they land. And to say nothing of if the need is for a vertical jump.

I mean, they're roughly similar if you're only considering the spell in combat. Outside of Combat, the 2014 spell is more powerful.

@nonymous Ok, I think I see what you're getting at there. I guess that could be true for a long jump, the 2024 version seems a lot better if you're going for a high jump.

#4. Some other interpretation
How I read it, and I would rule this at a table if I were running it, is the spell overrides the “Either way, each foot you jump costs a foot of movement.” clause once per turn for a willing creature. By spending 10 feet of movement, a targeted creature can jump up to 30 feet.
Similar to #1. Hella Buffed Interpretation, the creature is able to move 20 feet and then spend their remaining movement to jump (either as a Long Jump or High Jump) up to an additional 30 feet, still abiding by all other applicable rules for movement and jumping. Instead of deducting the distance of your jump from your movement, you would just deduct 10 feet, regardless of the distance jumped up to 30 feet.
As written, this doesn’t seem to enhance the distance you can naturally jump, other than reducing the movement cost of it once per turn.

I don’t see how this is different

@nonymous “When you jump, you make either a Long Jump (horizontal) or a High Jump (vertical).” “When you make a Long Jump, you leap horizontally a number of feet up to your Strength score[…]“ “However you’re moving with your Speed, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from it until it is used up or until you are done moving, whichever comes first.” My reading of this is that it overrides just the cost of moving, but you still jump, therefore you’re still limited by your Strength, but I can see why the other interpretations are popular, and I suspect the intent is closer to #1.

You think a character is limited by strength, even though the jump is magically empowered? Oh. No. That’s just wrong.

The alternative is that an 8 Str Wizard learning this as their first spell can make a 30 foot High Jump straight into the air, come crashing down taking 3d6 falling damage and probably die the first time they try to practice it. I don’t think this is how it’s intended to work, but I’m tired of soft patching WotC’s ambiguous language to guess how I think they wanted it. I fully expected this to be unpopular but that’s how I’d rule this as a DM of multiple multi-year spanning D&D 5e campaigns.

So, you’re wrong and patronizing. I must say I feel bad for your players.

The whole point of the spell Jump is to magically enhance the jump—not to slightly increase movement. The “up to” 30 ft clause obviously means they can jump shorter distances (e.g. to avoid an obstacle). A character’s strength is immaterial to the spell.
